# I cannot use Grid.Mvc and I get this error : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: model-view-controller, grid.mvc

I am using Grid.MVC, after I build and run the program, I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

this error apears when server tries to run this line from the view:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(..........
```

I installed and uninstalled different versions of Grid.Mvc but it still doesn't work!!! and I still get this error, even with another version of .net framework!!!

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: I'm using MVC 4.0.0.0

Comment: So hopefully that helps you?  The component you are adding is expecting 3.0.0, assuming you don't have this error when you remove it?  You could try a redirect in the web.config forcing it to use MVC 4, but check what you are installing is compatible with mvc 4.